# Not able to style the media webpart. Style option is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, style

After adding media webpart in sharepoint page, I am not able to add style to the media webpart. Style option is disabled. It's saying `The control is currently disabled`.

Can anyone please tell the possible reasons and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment(using Chrome, Edge and IE) and also meet the same situation as you: the style button is disabled.

Not sure but I guess that this option may be disabled in SharePoint Online.

I would suggest you submit a service request in the Microsoft365 admin center > Support > New service request. Then there will be more professional engineers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for you suggestion.. I will do that for sure..